# Why Spurious Eigenvalues comes from mixed states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, mathematical-physics

In this book [Many-Electron Approaches in Physics, Chemistry and Mathematics](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-06379-9)  they have the following definition at page 36

Definition 1 (Spurious spectrum) A real number $\lambda \in(-1,1)$ is called a spurious eigenvalue of $D^V$ (relative to the approximation scheme $W_n$ ), if there exists $\lambda_n$ in the spectrum of $\left(D^V\right)_{\mid W_n}$ converging to $\lambda$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, such that

- either $\lambda$ is not in the spectrum of $D^V$;
- or $\lambda$ is an isolated eigenvalue of finite multiplicity $M$ of $D^V$, but its multiplicity is overestimated in the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$. This means that there are more than $M$ eigenvalues of $\left(D^V\right)_{\mid W_n}$ counted with multiplicity in the interval $\left(\lambda-\varepsilon_n, \lambda+\varepsilon_n\right)$, for some $\varepsilon_n \rightarrow 0$.

in order to explain what Spurious Eigenvalues is they give the following example at page 37

We take $\mathfrak{H}=L^2(0,2 \pi)$ as Hilbert space and recall the Fourier basis
$$
\{1, \cos (n r), \sin (n r)\}_{n \geqslant 1} .
$$

So for $f(r)\in \mathfrak{H} $ we have
$$f(r)=\frac{a_0}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{n \geqslant 1} a_n \cos (n r)+b_n \sin (n r),$$

where
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi}|f(r)|^2 \mathrm{~d} r=\left|a_0\right|^2+\sum_{n \geqslant 1}\left|a_n\right|^2+\left|b_n\right|^2
$$
We now introduce the orthogonal projection $P$ onto the odd modes,
$$
(P f)(r)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{n \geqslant 1} b_n \sin (n r)
$$
the spectrum of this operator is $\operatorname{Spec}(P)=(0,1)$

Now we choose our approximation space $W_n$ by picking all the even and odd modes less or equal than $n-1$, and mixing the two $n$ modes as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
W_n=\operatorname{span}\left(1, \sin (r), \cos (r), \ldots, \sin ((n-1) r), \\
\cos ((n-1) r), \cos (\theta) \cos (n r)+\sin (\theta) \sin (n r)\right) .
\end{aligned} \tag 1
$$

In this basis the matrix $P_{\mid W_n}$  has only diagonal non zeros elements

$\operatorname{diag}(P_{\mid W_n})=(0,1,0,...,\sin^2 (\theta))$

and so the spectrum of $P_{\mid W_n}=(0,1,\sin^2 (\theta))$

and then they have

> This academic example reveals most of the nature of spectral
> pollution.A spurious mode is obtained when states from the spectrum
> above and below the considered gap are mixed together

But if  we choose the basis
$$
\begin{aligned}
U_n=\operatorname{span}\left(1, \sin (r), \cos (r), \ldots, \sin ((n-1) r), \\
\cos ((n-1) r), \sin (\theta) \sin (n r)\right) .
\end{aligned} \tag 2
$$
instead of $(1)$ we would obtain the same spectrum $\operatorname{Spec}(P_{\mid U_n})=(0,1,\sin^2 (\theta))$

I am not understanding why is the mixing of states that originates spurious states.

Comment: The problem is that $U_n$ is not normalized so $\sin^2 \theta $ is not a eigenvector